# How to convert string to bigint with parseInt() function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to create CRUD for user in my App, but got the error below when I passed it through Postman:

```
invalid input syntax for type bigint: "NaN"
```

Please what is wrong with my code below?

MY USER TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id BIGSERIAL,
username text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password text NOT NULL,
is_deleted boolean DEFAULT false,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL default now(),
last_login timestamp NOT NULL default now(),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

CRUD FOR GET ONE USER

```
function getSingleUser(req, res, next) {
  const showoneuserquery = 'SELECT * FROM user where id = $1'
  const user_id = parseInt(req.params.id);
  db.one(showoneuserquery, user_id)
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved ONE user'
        });
    })

    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Try this const user_id = BigInt(req.params.id);

Comment: @yash vadhvani thanks. I tried that before and got the error: Syntax Error: Cannot convert id to a BigInt

Comment: You can use a JavaScript lib called BigInteger.js for the purpose.it is an arbitrary-length integer library for Javascript, allows arithmetic operations on integers of unlimited size, notwithstanding memory and time limitations.

Comment: @yash how do I use it in the code?

Comment: What is your node.js version

Comment: see the answer below

Comment: @yash Node version is 10.16.3

Comment: update to the version 10.4.0

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: did that helped @Jetro Olowole

Comment: @yash thanks. If I update the node to 10.4, does it mean I don't need to install or use BigInteger.js

Comment: Yes you will be able to use the BigInt natively please check the answer below you will understand also check the link above in the comment.

Comment: Did you check the value of req.params.id?  Perhaps it is indeed "NaN"?

Comment: @Bjarni I enter 1 as the value when testing in Postman. I check the database and I can't see the NaN.

Comment: Well @JetroOlowole.  I'm suggesting the error is coming from the database and not the result of bigint conversion in the javascript code.  My best guess is that the req.params.id is actually NaN which is parsed by parseInt to NaN again into user_id.  It is then passed as string parameter to the select statement as "NaN" and postgresql raises the error.  Check what req.params.id is actually in the function with a log.  Then there is definitely something wrong elsewhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BigInt instead of parseInt if your node js version is above 10.4.0 this will come as native support

```
const user_id = BigInt(req.params.id);
```

If you don't have that 
install the big-integer npm module

```
npm i -S big-integer
```

require the bigint library at top of your file write.

```
const bigInt = require("big-integer");
```

and then in your code change this

```
const user_id = bigInt(req.params.id);
```

Comment: Sure @JetroOlowole Please read the link too so You will be clear in which browsers it got native support and which still are facing issues with it just for your knowledge and support.

Comment: I upgraded my node.js When I tried the code in Postman, I'm getting the error Syntax Error: Cannot convert id to a BigInt. @yash

Comment: It seems the BigInt is not being recognized in the updated node.js

Comment: It should use the library then

Comment: it is working for me in the node version 12 even i am able to convert in the browser's developer tools

Comment: can you give me a sample id @JetroOlowole

Comment: I enter 1 as the id in Postman because that was the value generated when I tested the create User route.

Comment: can you send me the url

Comment: I am developing locally and testing with Postman. My uri look like http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/id?id=1

Comment: have you console.log(req.parmas.id);

Comment: I didn't console.log the req.params.id because I setup the connection to log errors in a file.

Comment: comment all code in your function and log the req.params.id